# Display Field Name in a View Using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to display the property name of a field in a view(report).
**The Model:**

```
public class Report
    {
        [Display(Name ="Total Attendance")]
        public int Attendance { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total Offering")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public double Amount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "District Name")]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Weekly Service")]
        public int WeeklyServiceId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("WeeklyServiceId")]
        [Display(Name = "Weekly Service")]
        public WeeklyService WeeklyService { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Sdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Edate { get; set; }

        public string UsherName { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Report(Report model)
        {
            var startDate = model.Sdate;
            var endDate = model.Edate;
            var QueryResult = (from pay in _context.PaymentRecords.Include(p=>p.Location).Include(p=>p.WeeklyService)
                               //join a in _context.Locations on pay.LocationId equals a.Id
                               //join c in _context.WeeklyServices on pay.WeeklyServiceId equals c.Id
                               where (pay.DepositDate.Date >= startDate)
                               where (pay.DepositDate.Date <= endDate)
                               group pay by new { pay.LocationId,pay.WeeklyServiceId} into g
                               orderby g.Key.LocationId
                               select new Report
                               {
                                   LocationId= g.Key.LocationId,
                                   Attendance = g.Sum(x => x.Attendance),
                                   Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount),
                                   WeeklyServiceId =g.Key.WeeklyServiceId

                               });

            return View("Report", QueryResult);
        }
```

**The View/Report**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>SN</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Attendance)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WeeklyService)</th>



        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {
         int c = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                c++;
                <tr>
                    <td>@c</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  item.Location.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Attendance)</td>
                    <td>@item.Amount.ToString("C")</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.WeeklyService.Name)</td>


                </tr>
            }
            }

            else
            {

            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Result of the Above**
[image]
Note that Location is a model which has Name as a property as well as WeeklyService. But if i change the table data to LocationId and WeeklyServiceId, it will display the results with the Id. But I want it to display the Name of the Location and WeeklyService instead of their Ids.
[image]

Comment: "select new" and then you select your LocationId but not your Location

Comment: @StevenLemmens: I don't understand please.

Comment: What @StevenLemmens is trying to say. You have not initialised your Report object fully. There is no property `Location` inside your `select`. The issue is with the controller not the view.

Comment: @panoskarajohn: Please, how do i select the location and the WeeklyService in the controller. Please, give me an example with the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an exmaple of what we mean in the comments. 
You do not Initialize correctly the Report object.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Report(Report model)
    {
        var startDate = model.Sdate;
        var endDate = model.Edate;
        var QueryResult = (from pay in _context.PaymentRecords.Include(p=>p.Location).Include(p=>p.WeeklyService).ToList()
                           //join a in _context.Locations on pay.LocationId equals a.Id
                           //join c in _context.WeeklyServices on pay.WeeklyServiceId equals c.Id
                           where (pay.DepositDate.Date >= startDate)
                           where (pay.DepositDate.Date <= endDate)
                           group pay by new { pay.LocationId,pay.WeeklyServiceId} into g
                           orderby g.Key.LocationId
                           select new Report
                           {
                               LocationId= g.Key.LocationId,
                               Attendance = g.Sum(x => x.Attendance),
                               Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount),
                               WeeklyServiceId =g.Key.WeeklyServiceId
                               Location = g.Select(pp => pp.Location).First() // This is what you are missing
                               WeeklyService  = g.Select(pp => pp.WeeklyService ).First()// Also this

                           });

        return View("Report", QueryResult);
    }
```

The Location and WeeklyService is null. They are never initialized.

I am surprised you do not get a Null Ref Exception. You never mentioned one.
I am saying this because of the `(item => item.Location.Name)` in your View.
Hope this helps.

Note careful with client side evaluation  and EF core 3 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17878 , https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068

Also taken from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: Both properties are throwing error.From the group(g) when you dot the g, Location and WeeklyService are not part of the items that are displayed. It displays Key,Aggregate,etc.Hence, this can't be reference or initialized.

Comment: @Dave sorry updated the answer. Please let me know so i can update my answer if this is not working as well.

Comment: It throws error when the app run:InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new { LocationId = (p.LocationId), WeeklyServiceId = (p.WeeklyServiceId) }, ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: PaymentRecord ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember) IsNullable: False ) ) .Select(pp => pp.Location)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(),

Comment: @Dave this has to do with EF Core -> https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17878. Also check here all the GitHub issues for more info -> https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068

Comment: Take a look also here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client. To fix this add a ToLIst before Select.

Comment: @Dave Fully updated. Have a nice day. Feel free to edit it as well.